# I have a SQL query which is not run due to passed in value

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query which is not run due to 10k value i passed in operator

```
Select * 
From ABC 
Where df = 1
  And mno not in (select mno from ggg where  rc = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use `left join` then select those null `mno's` that mean it doesn't exist in `ggg`.

```
select * from (
    select t1.*, t2.mno as t2mno
    from abc t1
    left join ggg t2 on t2.mno = t1.mno and t2.rc = 1
    where t1.df = 1) t
where coalesce(t.t2mno, '') = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of your query and sub query contradict each others.
In main query you want all df=1 and in sub query result would be all df=1.
Ex. select column with value df=1 where result is not df=1.

Comment: Subquerry uses different table

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
From ABC
INNER JOIN (select mno from ggg where df != 1) as ggg on ABC.cf=ggg.mno
Where df = 1
```